# grub2 missing windows, manjaro

Tags: windows, grub2, dual-boot

Ive done some searching and am unable to figure out how to add my windows 10 drive (seperate HDD) /dev/sdd to the grub 2 menu.

I installed Manjaro linux on a seperate drive, windows is on the old one. Windows was installed first, I remember when I  first dabbled in linux with ubuntu, it detected and listed windows by default in grub.

**How do I add a windows entry to grub?**

`uname -r` **->** `4.4.17-1-MANJARO`

`grub-install --version` **->** `grub-install (GRUB) 2.02~beta3`

`sudo update-grub` **->**

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background: /usr/share/grub/background.png
Found Intel Microcode image
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-linux
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-linux.img
Found initrd fallback image: /boot/initramfs-linux-fallback.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.7-x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-4.7-x86_64.img
Found initrd fallback image: /boot/initramfs-4.7-x86_64-fallback.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4-x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-4.4-x86_64.img
Found initrd fallback image: /boot/initramfs-4.4-x86_64-fallback.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.10-x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-3.10-x86_64.img
Found initrd fallback image: /boot/initramfs-3.10-x86_64-fallback.img
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+/memtest.bin
done
```

`blkid | grep ntfs` **->**

```
/dev/sdd1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="01D1CED0D0E25BB0" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="576e6452-01"
/dev/sdd2: LABEL="Computer" UUID="01D1CED73B23FDC0" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="576e6452-02"
```

`/etc/fdisk` **->**

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a device; this may
# be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices that works even if
# disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>                           <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=596E-1D7B                            /boot/efi      vfat    defaults,noatime 0       2
UUID=e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a /              ext4    defaults,noatime,discard 0       1
UUID=b0dedb36-a45d-407f-be01-1da38f343149 /home          ext4    defaults,commit=60,noatime 0       2
UUID=5acc3a2a-fc46-4d5d-916c-3e42f1b77141 swap           swap    defaults,noatime,discard 0       2
tmpfs                                     /tmp           tmpfs   defaults,noatime,mode=1777 0       0


#windows drive
UUID=01D1CED0D0E25BB0                     /mnt/windows   ntfs    locale=en_US.utf8,dmask=022,fmask=022 0 2
UUID=01D1CED73B23FDC0                     /mnt/windows2  ntfs    locale=en_US.utf8,dmask=022,fmask=022 0 2
```

**EDIT**: added os-prober, grub-mkconfig

`sudo os-prober` **->** [Blank] returned nothing in terminal

`sudo grub-mkconfig` **->**

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
insmod part_gpt
insmod part_msdos
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="${saved_entry}"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

set menu_color_normal=light-gray/black
set menu_color_highlight=green/black

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd4,gpt2'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd4,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd4,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci4,gpt2  e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_CA
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_input console
terminal_output gfxterm
Found background: /usr/share/grub/background.png
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd4,gpt2'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd4,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd4,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci4,gpt2  e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a
fi
insmod png
background_image -m stretch /usr/share/grub/background.png
if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
  set timeout_style=menu
  set timeout=5
# Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
# unavailable.
else
  set timeout=5
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
Found Intel Microcode image
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-linux
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-linux.img
menuentry 'Manjaro Linux' --class manjaro --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a' {
        savedefault
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd4,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd4,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd4,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci4,gpt2  e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux linux ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a rw  resume=UUID=5acc3a2a-fc46-4d5d-916c-3e42f1b77141 quiet splash
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/intel-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-linux.img
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Manjaro Linux' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a' {
        menuentry 'Manjaro Linux (Kernel: linux)' --class manjaro --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-linux-advanced-e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a' {
        savedefault
                load_video
                set gfxpayload=keep
                insmod gzio
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd4,gpt2'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd4,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd4,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci4,gpt2  e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a
                fi
                echo    'Loading Linux linux ...'
                linux   /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a rw  resume=UUID=5acc3a2a-fc46-4d5d-916c-3e42f1b77141 quiet splash
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /boot/intel-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-linux.img
        }
Found initrd fallback image: /boot/initramfs-linux-fallback.img
        menuentry 'Manjaro Linux (Kernel: linux - fallback initramfs)' --class manjaro --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-linux-fallback-e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a' {
                load_video
                set gfxpayload=keep
                insmod gzio
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd4,gpt2'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd4,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd4,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci4,gpt2  e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a
                fi
                echo    'Loading Linux linux ...'
                linux   /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a rw  resume=UUID=5acc3a2a-fc46-4d5d-916c-3e42f1b77141 quiet splash
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /boot/intel-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-linux-fallback.img
        }
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.7-x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-4.7-x86_64.img
        menuentry 'Manjaro Linux (Kernel: 4.7.2-1-MANJARO x64)' --class manjaro --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.7.2-1-MANJARO x64-advanced-e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a' {
        savedefault
                load_video
                set gfxpayload=keep
                insmod gzio
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd4,gpt2'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd4,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd4,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci4,gpt2  e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a
                fi
                echo    'Loading Linux 4.7.2-1-MANJARO x64 ...'
                linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.7-x86_64 root=UUID=e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a rw  resume=UUID=5acc3a2a-fc46-4d5d-916c-3e42f1b77141 quiet splash
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /boot/intel-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-4.7-x86_64.img
        }
Found initrd fallback image: /boot/initramfs-4.7-x86_64-fallback.img
        menuentry 'Manjaro Linux (Kernel: 4.7.2-1-MANJARO x64 - fallback initramfs)' --class manjaro --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.7.2-1-MANJARO x64-fallback-e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a' {
                load_video
                set gfxpayload=keep
                insmod gzio
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd4,gpt2'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd4,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd4,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci4,gpt2  e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a
                fi
                echo    'Loading Linux 4.7.2-1-MANJARO x64 ...'
                linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.7-x86_64 root=UUID=e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a rw  resume=UUID=5acc3a2a-fc46-4d5d-916c-3e42f1b77141 quiet splash
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /boot/intel-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-4.7-x86_64-fallback.img
        }
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4-x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-4.4-x86_64.img
        menuentry 'Manjaro Linux (Kernel: 4.4.19-1-MANJARO x64)' --class manjaro --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.19-1-MANJARO x64-advanced-e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a' {
        savedefault
                load_video
                set gfxpayload=keep
                insmod gzio
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd4,gpt2'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd4,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd4,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci4,gpt2  e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a
                fi
                echo    'Loading Linux 4.4.19-1-MANJARO x64 ...'
                linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.4-x86_64 root=UUID=e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a rw  resume=UUID=5acc3a2a-fc46-4d5d-916c-3e42f1b77141 quiet splash
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /boot/intel-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-4.4-x86_64.img
        }
Found initrd fallback image: /boot/initramfs-4.4-x86_64-fallback.img
        menuentry 'Manjaro Linux (Kernel: 4.4.19-1-MANJARO x64 - fallback initramfs)' --class manjaro --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.19-1-MANJARO x64-fallback-e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a' {
                load_video
                set gfxpayload=keep
                insmod gzio
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd4,gpt2'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd4,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd4,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci4,gpt2  e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a
                fi
                echo    'Loading Linux 4.4.19-1-MANJARO x64 ...'
                linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.4-x86_64 root=UUID=e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a rw  resume=UUID=5acc3a2a-fc46-4d5d-916c-3e42f1b77141 quiet splash
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /boot/intel-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-4.4-x86_64-fallback.img
        }
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.10-x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-3.10-x86_64.img
        menuentry 'Manjaro Linux (Kernel: 3.10.102-1-MANJARO x64)' --class manjaro --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.10.102-1-MANJARO x64-advanced-e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a' {
        savedefault
                load_video
                set gfxpayload=keep
                insmod gzio
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd4,gpt2'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd4,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd4,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci4,gpt2  e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a
                fi
                echo    'Loading Linux 3.10.102-1-MANJARO x64 ...'
                linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.10-x86_64 root=UUID=e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a rw  resume=UUID=5acc3a2a-fc46-4d5d-916c-3e42f1b77141 quiet splash
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /boot/intel-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-3.10-x86_64.img
        }
Found initrd fallback image: /boot/initramfs-3.10-x86_64-fallback.img
        menuentry 'Manjaro Linux (Kernel: 3.10.102-1-MANJARO x64 - fallback initramfs)' --class manjaro --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.10.102-1-MANJARO x64-fallback-e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a' {
                load_video
                set gfxpayload=keep
                insmod gzio
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd4,gpt2'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd4,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd4,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci4,gpt2  e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a
                fi
                echo    'Loading Linux 3.10.102-1-MANJARO x64 ...'
                linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.10-x86_64 root=UUID=e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a rw  resume=UUID=5acc3a2a-fc46-4d5d-916c-3e42f1b77141 quiet splash
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /boot/intel-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-3.10-x86_64-fallback.img
        }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/60_memtest86+ ###
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+/memtest.bin
if [ "${grub_platform}" == "pc" ]; then
    menuentry "Memory Tester (memtest86+)" --class memtest86 --class gnu --class tool {
        search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root --hint-bios=hd4,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd4,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci4,gpt2  e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a
        linux16 /boot/memtest86+/memtest.bin 
    }
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/60_memtest86+ ###
done
```

`sudo parted /dev/sdd print` **->**

```
Model: ATA ST31000524AS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdd: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  525MB   524MB   primary  ntfs         boot
 2      525MB   1000GB  1000GB  primary  ntfs
```

Attempting to follow this [guide](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120232/dual-boot-windows-on-second-harddrive-uefi-gpt-system/120233#120233) while inside mounted system `/mnt/windows`, called `find . -name bootmgfr.efi` with no luck.
Inside `/mnt/windows/Boot` has no EFI folder or efi files of any kind

Mounted win10 iso, mounted EFI, entered `EFI/Microsoft/Boot/` and the file bootmgfw.efi already existed, added bootmgr.efi from win10 iso, ran `sudo grub-mkconfig`, grub still had no Windows option

Comment: Use [`os-prober`](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/os-prober/), `grub-mkconfig` will call it if it finds it.

Answer (score 1):

Please install `os-prober`: `pacman -S os-prober`

Also, it's `bootmgfw.efi`, not `bootmgfr.efi`.

The file `bootmgfw.efi` is not on the Windows partition, it's on the *[EFI System Partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition)*. Use `fdisk -l` on every disk to find the EFI partition. Then extract the file `bootmgfw.efi` from the [Windows 10 ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) to `$esp/EFI/Microsoft/boot`, where `$esp` is where the EFI partition is mounted. Then run `grub-mkconfig` and you are done.