# GRUB 2: Windows 10 is not automatically added, and a manual entry is not working either

Tags: grub2, uefi

[Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305834/grub2-missing-windows-manjaro) is a link to my previous question here asking this information, but that information is outdated as GRUB did not work when I originally had Windows 7 installed.

I installed [Manjaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manjaro) on separate drive, but Windows 7 was not showing up. I got frustrated, kind of broke Windows 7, replaced it with Windows 10 and am now trying to get Windows 10 to show up in GRUB (Windows 10 works).

So now the process. I have a bit too much distrust in installing Windows since I had it mess up my system before. As such, when I installed Windows 10 over my Windows 7, I physically disconnected the other drives.

1. I had Windows 10 placed on a bootable USB drive with a [GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) partition.
2. Installed Windows 10.
3. Reboot into Manjaro with all drives plugged in.
4. Ran `sudo grub-mkconfig` and `sudo update-grub`, but Windows was still not found

Added a custom entry in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.

menuentry "Windows 10" {
insmod part_gpt
insmod chain
set root='(hd4, msdos1)'
chainloader +1
}
```

Without any success. GRUB is saying "hd4,msdos2" not found (or similar).

I rebooted into GRUB, ran in command mode, and listed off all the drives using `ls`.

I found Windows 10 was installed:

- System Reserved `(hd4,msdos1)`
- C:/ `(hd4,msdos2)`

Browsing in GRUB, `ls (hd4,msdos2)/`, the [EFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) file was located: `(hd4,msdos2)/Windows/Boot/EFI/bootmgfw.efi`

I edited `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.

menuentry "Windows 10" {
insmod part_msdos
insmod ntfs
insmod chain
set root='(hd4, msdos2)'
chainloader /Windows/Boot/EFI/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

But without any success. GRUB is saying "hd4,msdos2" not found (or similar) again...

What should I do?

I am not sure 100%, but I do believe that I installed Manjaro (and Windows 10) as [UEFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface).

Output of `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 111.8 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0004e0a2

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1        2048 234438655 234436608 111.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


Disk /dev/sdc: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0005e1a9

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1        2048 1953520064 1953518017 931.5G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/sdb: 111.8 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xaf87c8bd

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 234438655 234436608 111.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


Disk /dev/sdd: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc443369b

Device     Boot   Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1  *       2048    1026047    1024000  500M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdd2       1026048 1953521663 1952495616  931G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


Disk /dev/sde: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D018CAAD-8426-4B8A-99FB-399757F9E3DB

Device         Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sde1       2048   9884859   9882812  4.7G EFI System
/dev/sde2    9884860 494259859 484375000  231G Linux filesystem
/dev/sde3  494259860 500118158   5858299  2.8G Linux filesystem
```

- `/dev/sde1` -> `/boot/efi`
- `/dev/sde2` -> `/`
- `/dev/sde3` -> `swap`
- `/dev/sdc1` -> `/home`

`/etc/fstab`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a device; this may
# be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices that works even if
# disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>                           <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=596E-1D7B                            /boot/efi      vfat    defaults,noatime 0       2
UUID=e96e9dc6-b686-419c-8070-532b71f0631a /              ext4    defaults,noatime,discard 0       1
UUID=b0dedb36-a45d-407f-be01-1da38f343149 /home          ext4    defaults,commit=60,noatime 0       2
UUID=5acc3a2a-fc46-4d5d-916c-3e42f1b77141 swap           swap    defaults,noatime,discard 0       2
tmpfs                                     /tmp           tmpfs   defaults,noatime,mode=1777 0       0

#windows drive
#UUID=847ACFC37ACFAFEA                     /mnt/windows   ntfs    locale=en_US.utf8,dmask=022,fmask=022 0 2
#UUID=C810D31310D306FA                     /mnt/windows2  ntfs    locale=en_US.utf8,dmask=022,fmask=022 0 2
```

Answer (score -1):

EFI needs the GPT file system. For "msdos1", try "gpt1."

Sorry, GPT partition numbering starts at 1, not 0. 
The number you need is for `/boot/efi`, which seems to be number 1.